# photoshop cs6-shape layers option

Tags: shapes, tools, pen-tool

In Photoshop CC, the pen tool contains the shape layers option. where can i find that shape layers option in Photoshop CS6? 
Everytime i do shape fill, it wont allow me to subtract front shape.
so, how do we find the shape layers option for the pen tool?

Comment: Your first sentence says, "In photoshop CS6, the pen tool contains the shape layers option." Your question is, "Where can I find the shape layers option in photoshop CS6?" .... I'm confused because you're answering your own question. What do you mean?

Comment: Im following an old guide for adobe photoshop CS4. i have an update for CS6. so, i know it's it in the pen tool, but where? for the CS6 update.

Comment: It's still a bit unclear to me. Care to show a screenshot of the guide and pinpoint what it is that you're missing in your photoshop? P.S. I retracted my vote to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need these steps:

1. (at the left) choose the "Shape" tool mode within the Pen tool, draw your shape and then:
2. (at the right) pick the desirable path operation and draw the "subtracter" or whatever

[image]